# Quotient groups and subgroups

Tags: group-theory

List all subgroups of $\;\mathbb{Z}_{12}/H,$ where $H=\{0,6\}\,$?

I can think of only finding the cosets but they don't work?

Help, please!

Comment: The cosets are elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}/H$.  You want subgroups, i.e. closed collections of these elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: $\Bbb Z_{12}/H$ is isomorphic to a cyclic group that you know by another name. If you can identify that group, you should have no trouble working out its subgroups, and you can then find their isomorphic counterparts in $\Bbb Z_{12}/H$.

Comment: @ Brian: I found {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}/H, and H and Z$_12$/H as the subgroups. Is that correct?

Comment: @JamesBond: Those are correct, and are of orders $3$ and $6$, respectively. There’s also a subgroup of order $2$, however, and the trivial subgroup of order $1$.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Brian Scott's answer above, there's another approach that is worth thinking about.

Recall that when you have a quotient by a normal subgroup $G/H$, the subgroups of this group correspond precisely to those subgroups $H'\subset G$ that happen to contain $H$.

What happens to the subgroups that dont contain $H$? Why are they not also subgroups?