# Question clarification request for: list all the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{20}/K,$ where $K=\{0,4,8, 12,16\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

For the following question, I am not sure if it is asking me about listing all the normal subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{20}/K$ or is this related to the first isomorphism theorem where $K$ is the kernel of a mapping say $f([x]_{20})=[5x]_{20}$, if that is the case, then $\Bbb Z_{20}/K$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_5$.

**Question**: List all the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{20}/K,$ where $K=\{0,4,8, 12,16\}$

Can someone tell me what I am supposed to do to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Notation: $K = 4\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ so $\mathbb{Z}_{20}/K = \mathbb{Z}_{20}/4\mathbb{Z}_{20}$, which makes it a bit more intuitive that there are $4$ distinct cosets, hence that this quotient group has order $4$.

Comment: Important lemma: a subgroup of $G/K$ is equivalent to a subgroup of $G$ that contains $K$.

Comment: @SammyBlack is the question asking me then what are the subgroups of the quotient group $\Bbb Z_{20}/K$ and not about the group $\Bbb Z_{20}$?

Comment: The subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}/K$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ that contain $K$, and the latter is a bit easier to think about. This is often called the [Lattice Isomorphism Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lattice_theorem) (a.k.a. the Correspondence Isomorphism Theorem) for groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=\Bbb Z_{20}/K$. The question is simply  asking you to find the (not *a priori* normal) subgroups of $G$. This is fairly simple, since

$$\begin{align}
|G|&=|\Bbb Z_{20}/K|\\
&=|\Bbb Z_{20}|/|K|\\
&=20/5\\
&=4
\end{align}$$

and there are only two groups of order four up to isomorphism.

Comment: wait, if that is the case, should not be the answer to this similar question to be incorrect: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386026/quotient-groups-and-subgroups the answer should be 6 there by Lagrange's theorem.  But the answer is 4 there.

Comment: I don't understand, @SethMai; the answer to *what* is $6$?

Comment: for the case of $\Bbb Z_{12}/K$ where $K={0,6}$, by lagrange theorem, the answer should be 6, since $|K|=2$ and $|\Bbb Z_{12}|=12$, which is similar to how you are showing me how to solve my problem.  But in that other question, they only listed 4 different subgroups.

Comment: No, @SethMai; there six is the order of the quotient, *not* the number of subgroups.

Comment: so the question is asking me about listing the subgroups of a quotient group which means I have to determine the order of the quotient group and then apply lagrange to see what are the possibilities?  In my case, it can only have two different subgroups since the factors of 4 are 0, 2 and 4.

Comment: Careful, @SethMai. One type of group of order four is $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$, which has *five* subgroups.

Comment: I meant since by lagrange, the order of $|\Bbb Z_{20}/K|=4$, then then it can have subgroups of order 0, 2 and 4.  I have to find out what they are and then listing them?

Comment: There is no subgroup of order zero, @SethMai. Each group has at least one element: the identity. Besides, $0\nmid n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. But yes, the orders of the subgroups must divide four in your case, indeed by Lagrange.

Comment: You have to find what the subgroups are and list them.

Comment: thank you for the clarifying the question for me.  Now that I know it is asking about quotient group, i know how to go about solving it.

Comment: You're very welcome, @SethMai.